# Ruby outputting in each loop no matter what?

Tags: ruby

I have no idea why this is happening. Here is the code:

```
def calculate_discount items
    items.each do |item|
        #Nothing here
    end
end

items = [5, 100]
calculate_discounts items
```

then when I run it in the command line I get:

```
5
100
```

Does anybody else know what's going on?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Ideally nothing. I want to use the values in the array to calculate a value but it's just outputting the values without me telling it to.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a value does not mean that the value is actually printed.

When you use IRB, the 'p' function displays values returned by functions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Sorry I was being stupid as I haven't coded ruby in a while. I forgot that ruby auto-returns the last value.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why there is output. Sure, the method returns the array that is passed in, but why is it being printed?

Comment: I was printing calculated discount further down in the file. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's functions always return a value. If you don't have a return statement, then Ruby returns the last value calculated in a function. Ruby's collection iterator also returns a value:

```
irb(main):018:0> [1,2,3].each do |item|
irb(main):019:1* end
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

So, in this case, 'calculate_discount' returns the elements of 'items'.